# Using checkboxes in many to many relationships in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am having a typical issue with using checkboxes. What I have is Employees and Skills. Each Employee can have many skills, and skills can belong to many Employees. This makes it a many to many relationship.

This are my Domain classes

```
class Skill {
    String name
    static hasMany = [users:Employee, resources:Resource]
    static belongsTo = [Employee]

    static constraints = {
        name unique: true, nullable: false, blank: false
    }

    String toString() { return name }
    String getDisplayName() { return name }
}

class Employee {

String name
String surname
Date birthdate
BigDecimal salary
Address address

static hasMany = [skills: Skill]
static belongsTo = [team:Team]

static constraints = {
    address nullable: false, blank: false
    name nullable: false, blank: false, matches: '[a-zA-Z\\-\'\\s]+'
    surname nullable: false, blank: false, matches: '[a-zA-Z\\-\'\\s]+'
    skills nullable: true, blank: true
    salary nullable: false, min: 16000.0, max: 60000.0
    team nullable: true
    birthdate max:new Date(use(TimeCategory){18.years.ago.getTime()})
}

String toString() { return "\nEmployee Information:\n Name: $name\n Surname: $surname\n " +
        "Date of Birth: $birthdate\n Salary: $salary\n"}
```

}

Employee domain works fine, I can create an employee with an address without any issues.

But when I try to add a skills to an employee, it doesn't do what I tell it too.
For instance, when I check two particular skills, it try to run and save, it would add all of the skills to the employee.

How do I tell the controller to only add what is been checked.

This is my code in the controller

```
@Transactional
def create() {
    params.each { println("$it.key -> $it.value") }
    def employee = new Employee(params)
    def address = new Address(params)
    def skills = Skill.list()

    if (params["create"]) {
        if (address.validate()) {
            address.save()
            employee.address = address
            params.remove("_s")
            skills.each { skill -> if (params["s"] != null ) {
                employee.addToSkills(skill)
                }
            }
            if (employee.validate()) {
                employee.save()
                flash.message = "Employee has been successfully created"
                redirect(action: "index")
            }
        } else {
            flash.message = "Ooops Error!!!!"
            render(view: "create", model: [employee: employee, address: address, skill: skills])
        }
    }
    [employee: employee, address: address, skill: skills]
}
```

This is my create.gsp

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<label>Select Your Competences:</label>
   <g:each in="${skill}" var="s" status="i">
    <br/>
    <g:checkBox name="s" value="${s.id}" checked="false"/>
     <label for="s">${s.name}</label>
 </g:each>
 </div>
```

Comment: When using `g:checkBox` the checked value is submitted using the name prefixed with an underscore. In your case `s` will always contain all values regardless of them being checked. Only the `_s` parameter will contain the checked values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your gsp as :

```
<label>Select Your Competences:</label>
   <g:each in="${Skill.list()}" var="skill" status="i">
    <br/>
    <g:checkBox name="s.${skill}" value="${skill.id}" checked="false"/>
     <label for="s">${skill}</label>
 </g:each>
 </div>
```

when you submitt this form you will get a params on your controller having values like this : `[skill:[_MsOffice:'', MsOffice:1, Managing:10, AgileCoach:3, _Coding:'']`

to get the ids of the checked values from the params do the following on your controller:

```
List<Long> skillIds = new ArrayList<Long>()

  params.skill?.each { s ->

   if(!s.getKey().startsWith("_")) {

    skillIds.add(s.getValue())
   }
  }
```

now on `skillIds` list you have a list of `Skill` ids for an `Employee`,
then pass this to your service and fetch skills to add to an `Employee` (using `Skill.getAll(skillIds)` or some other gorm operation)

you can see example here http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5722903798611968

Comment: This worked, but I went a slightly different way around it in the controller.
 
`for (skill in params.s) {
                    employee.addToSkills(Skill.get(skill))
}`

I little bit less code and easier to read. params.s comes from the checked checkboxes, were _s would be unchecked